# How to replace multiple values in a dataframe column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['john','mary','paul','john','mary'],
    'num_children':[0,4,5,28,28],
    'num_pets':[0,1,2,28,28]
})

df.replace({'name':{'john':'works','mary':'works'}})
```

I want to do the equivalent of the above code, replace all values in the 'name' column that are not "paul" with "works". The example only has three possible values so it's not too bad, but is there an easier way to do it for a column with much more possible values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
df.loc[df['name'] != 'paul', 'name'] = 'works'
```

Comment: why is it better than series.where or Series.mask?

Comment: When I change it to df.loc[df['name'] !={'paul','john'}, 'name'] = 'works', the whole 'name' column changed to 'works'. Essentially I want to exclude both 'paul' and 'john'  and change the rest to 'works'. Can you point out where I did wrong?

Comment: @GarryW If you have a list of names then I would use `isin`as proposed by @marcocarranza. Something like: `df.loc[~df['name'].isin(["paul","john"])] = 'works'`

Comment: @ansev I think the two solutions are substantially equivalent.

Comment: In this case you need: `df.loc[~df['name'].isin(['paul','john']), 'name'] = 'works'`..see my solution

Comment: If both solutions are similar, then why not vote? @baccandr

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple :

```
list = ['john', 'mary']

df.loc[df['name'].isin(list),'name'] = 'works'  

In [1]: df
    name  num_children  num_pets
0  works             0         0
1  works             4         1
2   paul             5         2
3  works            28        28
4  works            28        28
```

Comment: I guess that there is better to use `~df['name'].isin(["paul"])`.

Comment: or `df['name'].ne('paul')`

Comment: The code could be more compact, but it easier to understand if you are a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['name']=df.name.where(df.name=='paul','works')
print(df)
    name  num_children  num_pets
0  works             0         0
1  works             4         1
2   paul             5         2
3  works            28        28
4  works            28        28
```

---

or [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['name']=df.name.mask(df.name!='paul','works')
print(df)
    name  num_children  num_pets
0  works             0         0
1  works             4         1
2   paul             5         2
3  works            28        28
4  works            28        28
```

---

> for moren than one name

```
df['name']=df.name.where(df.name.isin(['paul','john']),'works')
print(df)
    name  num_children  num_pets
0   john             0         0
1  works             4         1
2   paul             5         2
3   john            28        28
4  works            28        28
```

or with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df['name'].isin(['paul','john']), 'name'] = 'works'
print(df)

    name  num_children  num_pets
0   john             0         0
1  works             4         1
2   paul             5         2
3   john            28        28
4  works            28        28
```

Comment: so many different ways of doing same thing. which is faster?